# Как исправить reduce/reduce конфликт?

Tags: c++, bison

Я пытаюсь написать парсер функций и переменных С++.

Имею вот такую грамматику(обрезана):

```
declaration:
    block_declaration
    | function_definition
    ;

block_declaration: simple_declaration;

simple_declaration: decl_specifier_seq init_declarator_list';';

decl_specifier_seq:
    decl_specifier
    | decl_specifier_seq decl_specifier
    ;

decl_specifier: type_specifier
    ;

type_specifier:
    simple_type_specifier
    | cv_qualifier
    ;

simple_type_specifier: type;

function_definition:
    decl_specifier_seq declarator function_body
    ;

function_body: '{' '}';

init_declarator_list:
    init_declarator
    | init_declarator_list ',' init_declarator
    ;

init_declarator: declarator initializer_opt;

declarator:
    direct_declarator
    | ptr_operator declarator
    ;

direct_declarator:
    declarator_id
    | direct_declarator '(' ')'
    | '(' declarator ')'
    ;

declarator_id: name | COLONCOLON name;

type:scope_id_seq_opt identifier;

name:scope_id_seq_opt unqualified_id;

scope_id_seq_opt:
    | scope_id_seq
    ;

scope_id_seq: scope_id_seq_opt SCOPE_ID COLONCOLON;

unqualified_id: identifier;

identifier:ID;
```

Конфликт reduce/reduce возникает в **direct_declarator** и связан с `| '(' declarator ')'` то есть если закоментировать эту строчку то всё хорошо, но теряется возможность распознать код вида `int (*var);`, а С++ поддерживает такой синтаксис. Как мне исправить данный конфликт?

Например парсим текст вида:

```
T add() {}
```

Лексер преобразует его в

```
ID(T) ID(add) '(' ')' '{' '}'
```

Должно быть так: `ID(T)` должен свернуться в **type**, а потом свернётся в  **decl_specifier_seq**. `ID(add) '(' ')'` должен свернуться в **declarator** через правило `| direct_declarator '(' ')'`.

Но из-за конфликта правила `| direct_declarator '(' ')'` с `| '(' declarator ')'` происходит вот так. В **decl_specifier_seq** сворачивается не `ID(T)`, а `ID(T) ID(add)`. А вот `'(' ')'` начинает сворачиваться в **declarator** по правилу `| '(' declarator ')'` и происходит **syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ID or SCOPE_ID**

Использовать glr парсер я не могу по причине использования [Lexical feedback](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Lexical-Tie_002dins.html#Lexical-Tie_002dins)

Comment: Ого, хороший вопрос. А какой второй конфликтующий путь?

Comment: Подождите, если у вас lexical feedback, то у вас type не должен парситься через identifier, правильно?

Comment: @VladD правильный комментарий. я же не слова не сказал по поводу второго пути. сейчас пофиксю.

Comment: @VladD эм.. не знаю при чём тут type или identifier. lexical feedback у меня в `function_body: { driver._lexer->setState(2); } '{' '}';` таким хаком я пропускаю всё что находиться в функции.

Comment: А, я думал, вы скармливаете лексеру информацию о том, где имя типа, а где (другой) идентификатор.

Comment: @VladD нет. в этом и проблема. я не могу использовать таблицу символов т.к. файл кода который я буду парсить возможно ничего не знает о том где найти файл с нужным типом. например буду парсить только один файл, а тип переменной будет объявлен в другом. я пишу не компилятор, а парсер.