# Как отличить декларатор от спецификатора?

Tags: c++

Пишу парсер для решения конфликта мне нужно каким то образом отличать спецификатор от декларатора.

Как это сделать без использования таблицы символов?

Вот примеры объявлений в которых нужно различать декларатор и спецификатор:

```
int i; // declarator is i
int (i); // declarator is (i)
int *i; // declarator is *i  
int **i; // declarator is **i;  
int &i = x; // declaratory is &i
int f(int a, int b, int c);
int (*pf)(int); // pointer to function returning int  
int *f(int i); // function returning pointer to int  
int (&pf)(int); // reference to function
int (X::* pmf)(); // pointer to member function of X returning int  
int* (X::* pmf)(); // pointer to member function returning pointer to int
int i, *j, f(int k);  // int, pointer to int, function returning int
```

Comment: скорее всего нужно будет написать небольшой парсер. **деклОратора** ???

Comment: @KoVadim могу использовать регулярки но какие? В лексере можно сделать правила вида: {ID}/[=;,(] { return NAME; } и оно было бы правильной, если бы не предпросмотр '(': он встречается после ID в двух разных случаях.`ID '(' ID ')'` и `ID '(' ')'`
В первом случае первый ID это спецификатор, во втором - тип.

Comment: Читать [книгу дракона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B) до полного понимания.

Comment: Стоит задача написать именно свой парсер? Если нет, то используйте готовый Antlr 4. Для него уже написано множество грамматик в том числе и для С++11. В синтаксическом дереве будут различия.

Comment: @KoVadim я читал книгу драконов и хорошо её понимаю. Этот вопрос нужен что бы разрешить конфликт из этого вопроса: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651652/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-reduce-reduce-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy Да. Стоит задача именно написать парсер. Antlr - это генератор парсеров. Для генерации я использую bison. Грамматики существуют и я их видел и не просто так упомянул таблицу символов.